# Why does an email rule testing for "<>" in header "Return-Path" not work?

Tags: email, mail-rules

I found that a good fraction of unwanted emails have the header "Return-Path" equal to "<>", so I thought that I could have an email rule to test for this and then move the email to a junk folder.  However, this rule does not work.

As a test--for one such email--I looked for another header that had a short value.  In that case email header "X-Originatororg" had the value "norcalasa.org", so I added a test for that value, which moved the email to junk.  That test worked.

What am I not understanding?

I am using a MacBook Air 2017 running MacOS Big Sur 11.6, with Mail version 14.